# kafka failing to start - too many open files

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka, server, devops, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to start the Kafka service but it is giving the below error.

[image]

```
● kafka.service - Apache Kafka server (broker)    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-11-17 06:16:12 UTC; 46min ago
     Docs: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html   Process: 10979 ExecStop=/opt/deployments/commoninfra/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 10409 ExecStart=/opt/deployments/commoninfra/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/deployments/commoninfra/kafka/config/server.properties  Main PID: 10409 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 17 06:16:11 atl-kafka2 kafka-server-start.sh[10409]:         at kafka.network.Acceptor.accept(SocketServer.scala:642) Nov 17 06:16:11 atl-kafka2 kafka-server-start.sh[10409]:         at kafka.network.Acceptor.run(SocketServer.scala:571) Nov 17 06:16:11 atl-kafka2 kafka-server-start.sh[10409]:         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Nov 17 06:16:11 atl-kafka2 kafka-server-start.sh[10409]: [2021-11-17 06:16:11,519] ERROR Error while accepting connection (kafka.network.Acceptor) Nov 17 06:16:11 atl-kafka2 kafka-server-start.sh[10409]: java.io.IOException: Too many open files Nov 17 06:16:12 atl-kafka2 systemd[1]: kafka.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Nov 17 06:16:12 atl-kafka2 kafka-server-stop.sh[10979]: No kafka server to stop Nov 17 06:16:12 atl-kafka2 systemd[1]: kafka.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1 Nov 17 06:16:12 atl-kafka2 systemd[1]: kafka.service: Unit entered failed state. Nov 17 06:16:12 atl-kafka2 systemd[1]: kafka.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How to check the below points
Find out from which microservice there are many connections to Kafka
A total number of established and waiting connections.

we tried to quick-fix by increasing ulimit but we are facing this issue every day. Need permanent solution

Comment: Hi nick -- can you make your issue reproducable? For example, how are you deploying Kafka?

Comment: @JoostDöbken it is in production has an environment, other 2 nodes are running smoothly just having issues in 2 Kafka server getting too many open file error while restarting service.

Answer (score 0):

To debug the issue, try issuing `lsof` on the Kafka broker process to get the list of files that kafka broker has opened. Topic partitions are folders.

Check your `segment.ms` or `segment.bytes` to see if Kafka is set to rollover new segments frequently which is ending up in creating a lot of files.

You may also want to consider adding new brokers *if needed*.

Ensure that you are using Kafka 2.1.1+. Check out this ticket
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7697